# How to use switch case -one in another case in shell

Tags: bash, shell, switch-statement, ubuntu-12.04

> Is there any possibility to use a case in another case in switch
>   statement in shell

like

```
case "$1" in 
  1)   do action 
  ;;
   2)
   1
    do action
   ;;
  3)
    2
  ;;
     ......
        ..........
        ............
```

Help me in this please

Here is an example for what i want

case $1 in 
1) 
echo 'level 1' 
;;
 2)
1 
echo 'level 2' 
3) 
2 
echo 'level3' 
........

Output: ./case 3

level 1
 level 2
 level 3

Comment: "one in another case"? Huh? If you want is fallthrough, there's a name for that, and you might consider using it.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
case "$1" in 
    1)   do action

        case "$2" in
            1)
                do action
                ;;

            another_option)
                echo blah
                ;;

            *)
                do default actions for this case
                ;;
        esac

        ;;
    2)
        1
        do action
        ;;
    3)
        2
        ;;
        ......
            ..........
            ............
```

The nested case is using argument 2

If you're not worried about the order, you can use `;&` to fall through to the next case in bash > 4.0.

```
case "$1" in
    3)
        echo 'level 3'
        ;&

    2)
        echo 'level 2'
        ;&

    1)
        echo 'level 1'
        ;;

esac
```

Comment: Cant we use the case 1 in 2 ?

Comment: @maker You have access to all the same variables in the second case's statements if that's the question. If it isn't I'm not sure what you were asking.

Comment: I tried it but its saying as 1 as unidentified token

Comment: @maker what do you mean case 1 in 2?  Do you mean pass "$1" to the nested case?

Comment: no in a case
 1)   echo 'level 1'
  2)  1
       echo 'level 2'

then if i give $1 as 2 then It should display
 ** level 1
   level 2**

Comment: I'll change my code a little, but in only works with bash > 4.0

Comment: @maker: Why are you using version 2?  Version 4 is already 6 years old.